# Пересобрать массив.Чтобы объединить 4 массива в один с теме же индексами

Tags: php, массивы, циклы

Подскажите есть 4 массива $a1,$b1,$c1,$d1
У каждого массива есть индексы 0,1...2,20 итд.
И как сделать чтобы новый асоциальный массив $allposti вмещал в себя под индексом 0 все индексы 0 этих четерых массивов т.е. 4ре значения под индексов 7 все 7-ые индексы этих четырех массивов.Чтото запутался и не то выходит.Через цикл for пробовал типа так - $a1['0'] .

Comment: А почему изначально нельзя послать массивы в удобочитаемом виде?

Comment: Переименовал если так удобней читать

Comment: Мой вопрос остался прежним

Comment: А можно пример массива, что на входе и что должно получиться на выходе?

Comment: @UKRman да вроде и так понятно. Но сам вопрос скорее не имеет смысла, потому что ТС некорректно с самого начала эти массива формирует и в итоге приходится какие-то костыли писать.....точнее, просить, чтоб написали

Answer (score 0):

используйте обычный `array_map`

```
$result = array_map(null, $a, $b, $c,$d)
```